# Sub Directories under getCacheDir()

Tags: java, android, directory, subdirectory

I'm trying to create sub directories in my apps cache folder but when trying to retrieve the files I'm getting nothing. I have some code below on how I created the sub directory and how I'm reading from it, maybe I'm just doing something wrong (well clearly I am lol) or maybe this isn't possible? (though I haven't seen anywhere that you can't). thank you all for any help!

creating the sub dir

```
File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "SubDir");
                        File file2 = new File(file, each_filename);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file2.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        stream = new FileOutputStream(file2);
                        stream.write(bytes);
```

reading from it

```
File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "SubDir");
    File newFile = new File(file, filename);

    Note note;

    if (newFile.exists()) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        ObjectInputStream ois;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File(file, filename));
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            note = (Note) ois.readObject();

            fis.close();
            ois.close();

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return note;
    }
```

I've also tried with this and nothing

```
String file = context.getCacheDir() + File.separator + "SubDir";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere in the code you posted where you actually create the sub-directory. Here's some example code to save a file in a sub-directory, by calling `mkdirs` if the path doesn't yet exist (some parts here need to be wrapped in an appropriate try-catch for an `IOException`, but this should get you started).

```
File cachePath = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "SubDir");
String filename = "test.jpeg";
boolean errs = false;

if( !cachePath.exists() ) {
    // mkdir would work here too if your path is 1-deep or
    // you know all the parent directories will always exist
    errs = !cachePath.mkdirs();
}

if(!errs) {
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(cachePath + "/" + filename);
    fout.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();
}
```

Comment: Wow, Silly me xD i guess i just figured writing to the directory automatically created it. whoops lol thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your directory with `mkdir`.

In your code:

```
File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "SubDir");
file.mkdir();
File file2 = new File(file, each_filename);
```